# Google play game services show sign in screen from google+ again

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

i am developing a realtime multiplayer game for android and an user requested this feature: She wants to see the sign-in screen from google+ account again, even after she was already signed in from another app.

How can i call that sign-in screen from google+ again? Even after an user has already signed in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better way but you can logout through code and call and it will show the login screen again... Not sure what you really want, can you explain better, for exemple when amd where you need that to happen.